# Is it possible to check if a Dataframe is a result of the application of only wide or narrow transformations in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How could I check in the Scala interface of Apache Spark if a given `DataFrame` is the result of only narrow transformations? For example, consider the code snippet below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("id-A", 1, 3),
  ("id-A", 5, 8),
  ("id-B", 1, 5),
  ("id-C", 3, 3),
  ("id-C", 2, 1),
)
.toDF("my_id", "col_1", "col_2")

val dfWithNarrowTransformations: DataFrame = df
.filter('my_id === "id-A")
.withColumn("col_3", 'col_1 + 'col_2)

val dfWithWideTransformations: DataFrame = df
.groupBy("my_id")
.agg(sum('col_1) as "col_4")

def hasWideTransformations(df: DataFrame): Boolean = ???

assert(hasWideTransformations(dfWithNarrowTransformations) == false)
assert(hasWideTransformations(dfWithWideTransformations) == true)
```

Would it be possible to implement a function `hasWideTransformations` that checks if wide transformations were applied regardless of the number of transformations?

To give more context, I'm interested in doing this to enable a constrained user interface supporting only the execution of transformations that have no state in the streaming mode such that they can be easily and consistently applied in both streaming and batch modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the physical plan and check whether the plan contains the string `Exchange`. If the plan contains exchange, it means that there is a shuffle thus you have a wide transformation.

To retrieve physical plan as a string, you can use inner dataset class field `queryExecution`, with its method `explainString`. Thus your method `hasWideTransformations` can be written as follows:

```scala
def hasWideTransformations(df: DataFrame): Boolean = df.queryExecution
  .explainString(ExplainMode.fromString("simple"))
  .contains("Exchange")
```

However, `queryExecution` field is internal spark's API and is tagged as unstable, so it might change in future version of Spark.